# playframework slick deprecation warning concerning driver and profile

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I got this message:

```
[warn] s.b.DatabaseConfig - Use `profile` instead of `driver`. The latter is deprecated since Slick 3.2 and will be removed.
```

my config looks like this:

```
slick.dbs.default.driver = "slick.driver.MySQLDriver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url = "jdbc:mysql://"
slick.dbs.default.db.user = ""
slick.dbs.default.db.password = ""
```

how do I have to change this to remove the warn?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
slick.dbs.default.profile = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url = "jdbc:mysql://"
slick.dbs.default.db.user = ""
slick.dbs.default.db.password = ""
```

The same thing in the HOCON format:

```
slick {
  dbs {
    default {
      profile = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$"
      db {
        driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url = "jdbc:mysql://"
        user = ""
        password = ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```